# MAC address changing in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I am trying to change the MAC address of my device. I tried the `ifconfig` way as well as the `macchanger` tool way. However although the MAC address changes on interface `eth0`. I do not get a DHCP based IP address. When I tried a `nework-manager restart`, then the old `eth0` MAC is assigned and I get an IP.

Is there a way to get an IP based on my new random MAC?

Please help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones ?

Answer (score -2):

I think, there is MAC filtering on router, switch, dhcp server. Also you may check there is static assign list MAC->IP or allow/deny list.