# Change MAC address via Terminal

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there any way to change MAC address via Terminal ?And  of course any command for this job ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way to change mac address on nic is:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx represent mac address

For wlan

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: ---   can you have a look at this persons issue and see if you help the guy  --- http://askubuntu.com/questions/439429/my-machine-hangs-up-on-networking-restart?noredirect=1#comment573648_439429  --- thanks

Comment: Ubuntu no longer has ifconfig installed by default. Not sure why this question doesn't allow updates. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones/1258805#1258805