# Create a new temporary MAC address to spoof free wifi (using terminal)?

Tags: networking, 20.04

### Background

I have a laptop with which I use to connect to a wifi. Normally, if I connect to some wifi, the laptop presents itself with its default MAC-address and I can display it using

```shell
ip a
```

where I can see the wifi device (`wlp0s20f3`), its IP-addresses and the presented MAC address (`18:1d:ea:6d:be:00`). This would be the MAC-address that I'd be using for people who have a wifi with MAC-address white list, etc.

Now imagine a Wifi, that limits the connection usage based on the MAC-address alone. To get around it, I could simply present a new *virtual* MAC-address once in a while and the Wifi would simply think it's a completely new device connecting.

### Question

**How can I create a new *virtual* wifi connection with a different MAC-address using the command line? Ideally with the `ip` command, not the deprecated `ifconfig` or other `network-tools`?**

So far I found out I can create a new virtual interface using

```shell
ip link add link wlp0s20f3 address 00:11:11:11:11:11 wlp0s20f3.1 type macvlan
sudo ip link set wlp0s20f3.1 up
```

But how do I present it to the wifi now?

*Note:
I want something I can set up temporarily and delete it later. Please include the commands to undo the setup as well. Thanks!*

Comment: Sounds dishonest to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change MAC address via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439459/change-mac-address-via-terminal)

Comment: Sadly no, that uses the old `ifconfig` commands which are now [deprecated](https://serverfault.com/a/503807). If anyone knows how these translate to the `ip`, that might be an answer to my question.

Comment: Actually it also completely overwrites the original MAC-address which is far from ideal. I prefer a new connection that can be easily erased without doing too much damage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change / spoof my MAC address and easily switch between multiple ones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones) (specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones/1258805#1258805)) Seems easily reversible by running the same commands with the original MAC address or likely even just a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for digging this up. It does, partially. I'd still prefer to create a new virtual device, because I know it should be possible. I just don't understand exactly how to work with the ARP tables and similar.