# Install Ubuntu into multi partioned in single hard disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

My Laptop has 3 primary partition and 1 logical partition (which is common share among the 3 primary partition). 1st partition is with Windows 7, 2nd with Windows 8 and i intend to install 3rd with Ubuntu. I have a boot menu (using boot-us boot manager) to show this 3 partition separately when i switch on my laptop.

1) Please advise me the steps how to install Ubuntu into 3rd partition on only without damaging any of my other partition (E.g. 1st, 2nd and logical partition to be intact).

2) How do i change or fix the mac address (to a new one) in ubuntu (via menu or command line)?

Thanks in advance
Saha

Comment: For mac change see https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones . Please, avoid asking multiple totally different question in same post. see https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

All installations deal in partitions.  When installing Ubuntu you have three options.  The first two options is to allow Ubuntu to use some automatic configurations.  The third option "Other" will allow you to specify the partition to use.  If you specify a partition, the partition(s) that you specify will be the only one(s) that will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

1) Tell the Ubuntu installer which partition to use. It will not touch any other partition.

2) Install [macchanger](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/macchanger-utility-for-manipulating-the-mac-address-of-network-interfaces-included-gui-utility.html) (or macchanger-gtk if you prefer a gui). Then

```
macchanger --mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0
```

Why do you want to change the mac? Your existing one will work fine.