# MacChanger not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I installed MacChanger on Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Air dual booting with OS X 10.8.5. It seems not to work.

This is what I do...

```
sudo ipconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -r wlan0
```

When I do that it comes up with...

```
Current - 28:11:22:33:44:55 (Apple)
Permanent - 28:11:22:33:44:55 (Apple)
```

(That isn't my real MAC adress)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need MacChanger or any other application to change your MAC address. Please refer to [this excellent question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones).

Comment: It seems there is no problem with changing the MAC address of most modern Ethernet NICs, but with wireless it's different - a large part of available cards doesn't support that. Are you able to change the MAC when using OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this post is an oldie, but it never hurts to write a few lines as I was struggling with the same problem.

First of all, the purpose of the program is to "change" the MAC address of your interface, connected to the Internet. Without going into further detail on how handshakes work and how does a computer "get an IP from a router", I'll give you the solution to the question you asked:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo macchanger -r eth0
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

You must firstly get your interface down, change the mac address and after that give a fresh restart to your system.
Now, I'm assuming that you're using a newer version of Linux, that's why I'm including the `systemctl` command there.

You can use the `/etc/init.d` directory to refer to the networking module or use the `service` command.

Either way, you'll get the same results.

If this doesn't help, proceed with the following:

- Check if the network-manager is working
- Check if your interface supports mac changes