# How to send the DHCP server a different hostname?(connecting to wifi with a fake computer name)

Tags: wireless, hostname, hacking

I want to connect to a WiFi network without disclosing my original Hostname(Computer Name) to the network.

i.e, I want to connect to WiFi networks with a different (fake) Hostname of my choice without altering my Computer Name.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure you can reliably do this...

Comment: I guess writing your own DHCP client is an option.

Comment: +Hennes, Could you please elaborate '**writing own DHCP client**'

Comment: Your hostname is your computer name, isn't it?

Comment: @SuperSluether Yes,  If I connect to a wifi network and if anybody goes to router page, In **connected devices** It shows my PC-name.

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV So if your hostname is your computer name, you can't change just one. On a sidenote, why does it matter if people can see your PC name? The router page is always locked down on public Wi-Fi, and your home Wi-Fi should have a password on the network anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hostname newname` will *temporarily* change your host name till the next reboot. Its the closest thing to what you want, *but definitely not what you **need:***

Things to note - your router may cache the old host name, so it might not help at all, depending on what you're really trying to do - but [fabby's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/715215/344926) covers that in detail.

Comment: how about adding `hostname newname` in a script and running it everytime computer boots.

Comment: That's as good as permanantly changing the hostname.

Comment: but isn't it true that in this case the hostname and the computer name are  different.

Answer (score 2):

I could just tell you to go look in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and add a script there to generate a random host name every time you connect to any WiFi network, and then change it back to the original using `/etc/network/if-updown.d/` *but will this help you?*

## No!

Because that still divulges your IP address, and more importantly: [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) which is an address *uniquely identifying your machine*, so you should [spoof that too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones) ***depending on your use case.*** (which isn't very elaborately documented in [your question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/713482/1)...)

Alternatively, [buy this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) which explains TCP/IP in detail and then you'll know as much as I know...

#### ;-)

Comment: I don't like the air of this answer.

Comment: @hakermania: Thank you for leaving a comment with the downvote...  shall we [continue this discussion in chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: I think it's better now. I felt it was belittling OP.

Comment: @hakermania **:D**  VishwaPrakash and me were discussing this in chat (that's why I invited you) and I have a very dry sense of humour!  I'm pretty sure he wasn't offended...  **>:-)** *Double thanks for removing the downvote.* (I always leave comments with downvotes as well)

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch the sarcasm. Everything's alright!