# How to change mac address of my WiFi device?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ip-address

I wanted to connect to WiFi Networks With a fake Mac address. In Windows, I changed **Network address** in Network devices. Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: This Might already have an answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might already have an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones).

You can try this:

1. Install macchanger `sudo apt-get install macchanger macchanger-gtk`
2. `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`

   NOTE: wlan0 my change according to your card, please check `ifconfig`.
3. `sudo macchanger -a wlan0`
4. `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
5. now I suggest once disabling and enabling of Wifi.

done.

Comment: Is there a command to do the 5th step also?

Comment: Is this a permanent change?

Comment: No, This is a temporary change. you will have to change it every time you restart.