# File location of Cloned Mac Address

Tags: network-manager, ubuntu-gnome

Graphically, I would do the following to spoof mac address for a specific connected network:

1. Select the gear icon of the connected network:
   [image]
2. Enter the required value in **Cloned Address** Field
   [image]

Now, how can i do the same from the terminal for a connected network?
Also, i have looked at other posts from *askubuntu* but none worked. After spoofing the mac and bringing the network up, default settings are seen. I think that is a problem with my network hardware - Intel. Also Intel mentioned in their website that **Intel does not support this practice of mac spoofing** (They have removed the official link but here is a link to the [Superuser discussion page](https://superuser.com/questions/966084/change-mac-address-of-intelr-dual-band-wireless-ac-7260)).
I think linux spoofs mac in a different way without actually requiring much of hardware level access. So if you can give me the *location of the file* where the value of **Cloned Address** is saved, maybe i can change the address by changing the content of that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change / spoof my MAC address and easily switch between multiple ones?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones)

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me. After spoofing the mac and bringing the network up, default settings are seen. I think that is a problem with my network hardware - Intel. Also Intel mentioned in their website that  **Intel does not support this practice of mac spoofing**  ( [Superuser discussion page](https://goo.gl/xh1gWj)). I think linux spoofs mac in a different way without actually requiring the  hardware level access. So if you can give me the _location of the file_ where the value of **Cloned Address** is saved, maybe i can change the address by changing the content of that file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the changes in the file relative to your connection, on:

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

probably

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Gauri_1.nmconnection

If you want to change the MAC of the interface:

```
$ ifconfig <interface-name> down
$ ifconfig <interface-name> hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
$ ifconfig <interface-name> up
```

Or if you want to change the 'Cloned Address' option (better approach imho):

```
$ nmcli c down "Gauri_1"
$ nmcli c modify "Gauri_1" wifi.cloned-mac-address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
$ nmcli c up "Gauri_1"
```

Changing the 'Cloned MAC Address' is usually a better option then changing the interface MAC address directly, depending on your network card it can be blocked.