# Rename device ID as returned by nmap

Tags: nmap

I would like to rename a device on my network as I have several devices from the same mfg. For example, an Asus wireless router shows the same mfg name as an Asus motherboard (connected by Ethernet), as such:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.110
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
MAC Address: (mac) (Asustek Computer)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.105
Host is up (-0.100s latency).
MAC Address: (different mac) (Asustek Computer)
```

The computer is running Ubuntu MATE, so while I am not sure that the router can be renamed (since it's a limited embedded device after all), the computer might have tools to do so. However, I am not sure how it is to be done. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think that it is the devices that answers back with ID, but nmap that has a database over which MAC address ranges that belongs to which manufactures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not "names" on a network that you can find with a name resolution ([DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)).

`nmap` is just reporting the the manufacturer for the mac addresses it found. 
Specifially, `nmap`looks up the prefix - first 3 hex values - of the address [in this database](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nmap-mac-prefixes).

If, for some reason, you still need to have different manufacturers show up after an `nmap`scan, you can [change/spoof your mac address in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/81648/783023). Your Asus router might also have an option for this.

If you want "names" (i.e. myhost.example.com) on your network, then we are talking about DNS records.

I'd suggest looking into

- running a DNS server - flavour [bind9](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto)
- running a DNS server - flavour [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq)
- static DNS names in [/etc/hosts files](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/hosts.5.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I might go the DNS route - the last option sounds most applicable. As to the MAC address being the source for the "names". the more you know :)